# pocketsphinx simple recognition in python or bash

Tags: python, bash, pocketsphinx

So as far as my recognition working with command :

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us \
-lm 3199.lm -dict 3199.dic -inmic yes
```

i would like to make it if recognized YES do this if NO do that 
how do i do that one ? is enyone got simple working example ?

Comment: It is better to do that in Python, not in bash. Python examples are available in sources.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do that in Python, not in bash. Something like this:

```
from os import environ, path
import pyaudio
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "../../../model"
DATADIR = "../../../test/data"

config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, '3199.lm'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, '3199.dic'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
decoder = Decoder(config)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                result = decoder.hyp().hypstr

                print 'Result:', result
                if result == 'yes':
                      print 'Do whatever you want'

                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

Further python examples are available in [sources](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/tree/master/swig/python/test)